# jQuery: fire click event on dynamically added HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick, dynamically-generated

I add dynamically a form into a `<div>` using jQuery with some data retrieved via Ajax (it's made to update some records). Problem is that i'm not able to fire a click event on this form as i assume it is created after the document comes ready. I need to fire this event to call Ajax again and save the new data in the db.

Basically, this creates the form into the `<div id="#result">` :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        [...]
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(
                '<form name="form_name_here">' +
                    '<input type="text" value="' + data[0].it + '">' +
                    [...]
                    '<input type="button" id="update_record" value="Save"> ' +
                '</form>'
            );
        }
    });
});
```

But then this won't work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        [...]
    });
    $('#update_record').click(function () {
        console.log('test');
    });
});
```

I tried also `$('#update_record').on('click', function() {` with no success.

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle with this in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).on("click", "#update_record", function(){
});
```

Comment: thanks, this works...so is this the correct and official way to fire an element added after?

Comment: As far as i know, it is. :)